# How can I undo a thumbs down on Pandora Shuffle station?

Tags: pandora

Today I accidentally gave a thumbs down to a song I like on the shuffle station. I know how to remove a thumbs down on other station (station details, delete the song in question), but I don't know how if it was on the shuffle station.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> If you accidentally press thumbs down on a track you can quickly swipe back to that song on the web or on the app to see a thumbs down. Tap on thumbs down to undo that choice, or tap on
>   thumbs up if you like the track. If you need to make this change on an
>   older song you will need to go to the station options on the web or on
>   the app.
>
> Tap to see your Pandora thumbs down history in the app. Tap to see
>   your Pandora thumbs down history in the app. On the Pandora app you
>   can tap on the upper right corner on the thumbs up icon. This will
>   show you the station details so that you can see your thumbs up and
>   thumbs down history.
>
> On this screen you will see a listing of thumbs down and thumbs up
>   options at the top of the app. Tap on the thumbs down icon to see your
>   thumbs down history for that station. You can see this in the photo
>   above. You can tap the thumbs up option to see that history and make
>   any corrections.

Source: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/02/16/how-to-undo-thumbs-down-on-pandora/